# Correct way to return a C# object to Android via RESTful JSON webservice

Tags: c#, android, json, wcf, rest

When returning data from a WCF RESTful webservice via JSON to an android app, currently I've designed the webservice to follow the Request/REsponse pattern, ie

```
public GetStorySeedsResponse GetStorySeeds(GetStorySeedsRequest request)
{
...
}
```

This is ok for the request, I create a `JSONObject` in Android and set that as the Post body, and WCF seems to receive it and decode it into a `GetStorySeedsRequest` object. The problem is when I return the above response object, this contains a `List<StorySeed>()` where the StorySeed class has a whole number of parameters, including image data. Currently when I try and decode this as a JSONObject in Android like so

```
String responseEntity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONObject seeds =  new JSONObject(responseEntity);
```

It is timing out and the array length seems to blow out the IDE, so I'm assuming I'm handling the response to Android via JSON incorrectly.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: you can see your returned data by putting your web_url in any browser OR you can take help of fidler as well.

Comment: i would also recommend using fiddler to view your traffic. can be very telling.

Comment: How can I use Fiddler to monitor traffic from Android emulator to a local webservice on port 82? In android, the base address is "http://10.0.2.2:82/ and fiddler doesnt seem to pick this up